# C# Outlook 2007 add-in: Recursive parsing of mail items

Tags: .net, outlook-2007

I'm writing an add-in for Outlook to parse all mails within a folder by clicking on a custom context menu button.  I've got the button hooked up, but when trying to use the foreach loop within the folder to check the mail items it only seems to check the first one.

I grab the folder details here:

```
void Application_FolderContextMenuDisplay(Office.CommandBar CommandBar, ***MAPIFolder Folder***)
```

I then pass it to a parser:

```
public void checkFolder(MAPIFolder folder)
    {
        MailParser parser = new MailParser();
        foreach (MailItem item in folder.Items)
        {
            parser.parseMail(item);
        }
    }
```

It's the foreach here that seems to fail.

Any ideas? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: A more descriptive error than "it fails" would aid us considerably :D

Comment: He was explicit- it only iterates the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not extremely familiar with the outlook object model, but at a glance I would say the problem is you're incorrectly assuming that all of the items in a folder are `MailItem` instances.  They could also be objects like `ContactItem`.  You need to explicitly check to see if the value is a `MailItem` like so

```
foreach ( object current in folder.Items ) {
  MailItem mi = current as MailItem;
  if ( mi != null ) { 
    parser.parseMail(mi);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Extensions.Linq** API, which allows the type safe retrieval of items:

```
public void checkFolder(MAPIFolder folder)
{
    MailParser parser = new MailParser();
    IQueryable<Mail> query = folder.Items.AsQueryable<Mail>();
    foreach (MailItem wrappedItem in query)
    {
        parser.parseMail(wrappedItem.Item);
    }
}
```

Here the the `Mail` type is a subclass of `OutlookItemBase<TaskItem>`. It has an `Item` property which returns the `MailItem` COM object. It will also safely filter out non-compatible types without throwing an exception, so you don't have to add *null* checks.

The *Extensions API* also solve the missing base class problem for the items, so you can finally access `UserProperties` and such through the non-generic `OutlookItem` base class. Also the API supports some attributes, which can add some performance boost to the *Linq* queries, by executing them on Outlook side, instead over COM. Unfortunately they are not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that MAPIFolder.Items isn't strongly typed, yet you're iterating over it as if it is.  I'd suggest going with:

```
foreach(object item in folder.Items)
{
  if (item is MailItem)
    parser.parseMail((MailItem)item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is useful for a collection that implements the `IEnumerable` interface.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.items.aspx), it would appear that particular `Items` collection does not implement `IEnumerable`.  Try using a `for` loop instead:

```
int c = folder.Items.Count
for (i=0;i<=c;i++)
{
   //Do your thing
}
```